# Trigger 2 mouseover events after hovering on a Bar of Bar Chart created using d3.js?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, tooltip, mouseover

In the following d3.js code:

```
    svg.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("transform", "translate(10,0)")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.thread_id); })
            .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
            .attr("y", function(d) { return y(+d.traffic); })
            .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(+d.traffic); })
            .on('mouseover', tip.show)            // First time call to show a tooltip
            .on('mouseover', justChecking)        // Second time to call a Function
            .on('mouseout', tip.hide);
```

When I execute this code, only the second function output is shown but the tooltip disappears.

I want to call both of them on mouseover, i.e., call the function as well as show the tooltip. Any ideas are appreciated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any event handler you attach overwrites previously attached event handlers. You can however call both of your functions in the same handler:

```
.on('mouseover', function(d, i) {
  tip.show(d, i);
  justChecking(d, i);
})
```

Comment: If for some reason this doesn't work for you, you can [add a "namespace" to the event](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-on), and it will only over-write other event handlers with the same event type and namespace.  `.on("mouseover.tip", tip.show).on("mouseover.check", justChecking);`